# Can Muslims be considered Muslims and Christians at the same time in the sight of God?

Tags: trinity, christology, islam, comparative-religion, divinity

There are a number of Christians (groups that believe in Christ and name themselves "Christian") who don't believe in the Trinity. Many of these are broadly considered Christians.

Muslims are non-Trinitarians, but they believe in Jesus and claim that they follow his teachings.

Why won't Muslims be considered Muslims and Christians at the same time in the sight of God?

Comment: I vote for the question to be reopened because after the edit it is possible to objectively show why most Christian groups (even the non-Trinitarian ones) *still* wouldn't consider Moslems to be Christians despite Islam's high view of Jesus as true prophet, teacher, and even born of the Virgin Mary (Maryam)!  The answer should explain specifically Christian view & teachings of Jesus (apart from being God incarnate) that Islam cannot hold.

Comment: Mahmudul, please be judicious with your edits. I realize English is almost certainly not your primary language, but you are making the grammar non-trivially worse and, while I am sympathetic to some of your other changes, I am concerned they are skirting with leaning the question back towards its original form in which it was deemed unsuitable.

Comment: Would you please allow us some time to present an answer that fully addresses your question?  This could take a day or two to do it justice!

Comment: Mahmudul, that's actually not how this SE works. It's especially not how it works when a question is deemed inappropriate and someone edits it in an attempt to make it useful to the OP but also appropriate to the SE. I also dispute your claim that your edit changes the meaning of the question meaningfully, while it *assuredly* makes it grammatically worse.

Comment: @Matthew After my question being closed I changed the whole question. What's the problem with changing the meaning? One another question : you are talking about language quality. So is this site only for native english people? Then I'll consider leaving the site. I'm not an english. But I have to keep the meaning of the question what actually is my question.

Comment: @MahmudulHasanJabir, nothing is wrong, and the change is why it was reopened. SE (here and in general) isn't only for native English speakers, but IMHO your edits did not alter the meaning of the Question relative to mine.

Comment: @MahmudulHasanJabir non-native speakers of English are certainly very welcome on this site.

Comment: @MahmudulHasanJabir. Christians who reject the trinity accept that Jesus is the promised messiah and that He  alone is the one through whom Almighty God offers a pathway to redemption and salvation.  Do Muslims feel the same?  Don’t Muslims believe that Mohammad is the greatest prophet and that Jesus is another lesser prophet?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to provide an objective answer here on who might be considered Christian "in the sight of God." "For my thoughts are not your thoughts, neither are your ways my ways" (Isaiah 55:8–9). We can answer from the perspective of our own beliefs or from the perspective of a denomination, but not from the perspective of God. Is "in the sight of God" an integral part of your question?

Comment: Never mind Christians calling Muslims Christian. Which muslims want to call themselves Christian? I've seen this line of thinking offered on the site before, but I've yet to see a self identified Muslim Christian.

Comment: I wonder what is the real motivation that apparently some Muslims want to be technically Christian, but would never call themselves Christian. I feel like there's a social and cultural component that is obscured to outsiders.

Comment: I thought questions on this site had to be framed from the perspective of a particular Christian denomination to be on topic?

Comment: The point is, muslims believe Jesus was muslim. Islam means submittimg to God. So jesus and all prophets submitted to God. So Muslims validate "following and believing Jesus" in order to be muslims. But other people names "following and believing jesus" is christianity. It's just a naming problem among people. But God never named christianity in bible. That's why my question is "in the sight of God".

Comment: If we keep changing this question from something that can be objectively answered from Christian tradition to something only God can answer this question is not going to work for the site.  If you say something like "In the Sight of God" and don't put any context around it, then you're inviting personal opinion.

Answer (score 12):

#### What are *specifically* Christian teachings

Most religions agree with Jesus's teachings such as loving God, loving fellow human beings, forgiving enemies, almsgiving for the poor and downtrodden, fighting for justice (especially for victims of injustice), and conducting a good and responsible life.  But following these ethical principles **is not enough for one to be called a Christian**.

Many religions are monotheistic.  In addition, Islam and Judaism, being the other 2 [Abrahamic religions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abrahamic_religions) like Christianity, believe in a God that

- operates in history
- sends His prophets to warn humankind
- gives us ethical commandments to be obeyed
- is almighty and all seeing, thus to be glorified, feared, and respected
- will judge everyone after death with the attendant rewards & punishment

But believing in the One God described above **is not enough for one to be called a Christian**.

Below are specifically Christian teachings about Jesus that according to all Christian groups, **including non-Trinitarians** (such as *the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints, Jehovah's Witnesses, Biblical Unitarians and the Swedenborgian Church*) **are essential for a Christian but are denied by a Muslim**:

1. The New Testament is considered scripture (i.e. inspired by God and is thus considered revelation and authoritative), so what the New Testament says about Jesus **take precedence** over other sacred texts like the Qur'an.
2. Jesus truly died on the cross and was resurrected by God.  It was *not* a resuscitation (where one will die again) because Jesus was resurrected into a glorified body that will never die again, the "first fruit" of the general resurrection given to all faithful Christians after death ([1 Cor 15:20-22](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Corinthians%2015%3A20-22&version=CSB)). This is an extremely important teaching for Christians because this is **the basis of our hope** to one day to be resurrected bodily just like Jesus.
3. Jesus is the ["Passover Lamb"](https://www.gotquestions.org/Passover-Lamb.html) provided by God to take away the sins of the world, a key aspect of Jesus denied by a Muslim.  But *in addition* to taking away the punishment for sins, Jesus in his human nature **voluntarily agrees to BE the lamb** because Jesus loves sinners, thus demonstrating the character of a true friend (John 15:13) who is **compassionating with us** who still suffer from the *effect* of our own sins although we are no longer condemned (Rom 8:1).  That is why having faith in Jesus as our Savior (accepting the gift) and becoming Friend with Jesus (by extending Jesus's friendship to others in love, [John 15:12-17](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=john+15%3A12-17&version=CSB)) is the essence of being a Christian.
4. Baptism and the Lord's Supper are two essential rituals connected to Jesus, His death, His resurrection, and His sacrifice. But since a Muslim doesn't believe those 3 essential aspects of Jesus (#2 and #3 above), both rituals would be meaningless for a Muslim.  There are disagreements of what these 2 rituals signify among Christians, but I think all groups agree that a key prerequisite of the rituals is **union with Jesus** who give us [New Life](https://www.gotquestions.org/new-creation.html), [Light](https://www.gotquestions.org/light-of-the-world.html) and spiritual gifts (faith, hope, love, etc.) through the [**indwelling spirit of Jesus**](https://www.gotquestions.org/indwelling-of-the-Holy-Spirit.html) (also called the Holy Spirit) in a believer's soul ([John 14:15-17](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John+14%3A15-17&version=CSB)).  But this key doctrine of the spirit of Jesus indwelling in the souls of believers is denied by a Muslim.
5. Jesus is the **[head of the church](https://www.gotquestions.org/head-of-the-church.html)**, and the **[church is his body](https://www.gotquestions.org/body-of-Christ.html)** that *also* mediates his presence ([God with us](https://www.gotquestions.org/God-is-with-us.html), "Immanuel"), **continuing his bodily presence *spiritually* in the bodies of Christians** after he ascended to heaven in his glorified body.  To a Christian's self understanding, this notion of belonging to the spiritual body of Christ is extremely important, because this is the bodily mechanism of spreading love and other spiritual gifts obtained in point #4 above.  In contrast, to a Muslim Jesus is no more than God's messenger ("Rasul Allah"), despite being one of the 5 *ul al-'azm* (arch prophets) second in rank to Muhammad (pbuh), until Jesus [comes again shortly before Judgement Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus_in_Islam#Second_Coming).

**CONCLUSION**: Because a Muslim cannot believe and practice the above 5 points, **a Muslim cannot be a Christian simultaneously**, even though the Muslim respects Jesus highly as an arch prophet, believes many miraculous aspects of Jesus as empowered by God, obeys most of his ethical teachings, and anticipates Jesus's second coming.

#### Did Jesus say that the New Testament is the final and the last revelation?

The following New Testament verses imply that **God has *already* revealed Himself in the fullest extent possible** to a human being by taking on the form of **a human life**, not just prophecy / spiritual presence as in the Old Testament.  By this logic, what more is there to reveal?

1. Some of what Jesus said such as John 14:6:

   > "I am the way and the truth and the life. No one comes to the Father except through me."
2. What Jesus said to John in a vision as recorded in Revelation (such as Rev 22:12-13:

   > "I am the Alpha and the Omega, the First and the Last, the Beginning and the End"
3. Paul's teaching that Jesus is the "image of the invisible God" (Col 1:15)
4. John's teaching that Jesus is the preexisting God the Word who took on flesh (John 1:1-18)

As for **revelation of further teachings**, very early in the church history there was a sect called [Montanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montanism) which was rejected by the majority of local churches (each headed by a bishop) not long after, affirming that there will *NOT* be new prophecies which supplant or correct the teachings codified in the New Testament.

Of course this doesn't prevent later movements such as one started by the 19th century [Joseph Smith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Smith) who claimed that God gave him further revelation (later recorded in the [Book of Mormon](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/bofm?lang=eng)) to "supplement" the New Testament.  The logic was that the majority Christian leaders corrupted Jesus's teaching ([Great Apostasy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Apostasy)).  This seems to be similar logic of Islam as well.

**Which one is true?**  I think it comes down to which interpretation you trust: will you trust the majority and surviving witness of the [Apostolic tradition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacred_tradition) that closed the NT canon and provided the authoritative interpretation of the Bible by figures such as St. Irenaeus, St. Augustine, and other early church fathers? Or will you trust later and minority interpretation?

At any rate, even the non-Trinitarian movements we had so far hold to the 5 Christian *specific* teachings I described above, which STILL put them miles apart from Islam's teaching about Jesus.

#### Being a Christian / Muslim "in the sight of God" vs. Christianity

Responding to your comments (paraphrased below):

> 1. Muslims believe Jesus was muslim. Islam means submitting to God. Jesus and all prophets submitted to God. Also, Islam has the most similar teachings with Christianity compared with other religions.  So Muslims consider "following and believing Jesus" a part of being Muslims.  I'm not talking about Muslims to be considered Christians **in the sight of an ideology** called Christianity. I'm talking about **in the sight of God**. In God's sight, won't Muslims be considered believers and followers of Jesus in the hereafter?
> 2. It's **people** who calls "following and believing Jesus" to be Christianity. It's just a name created by people.  But **God never named Christianity** in the Bible. And Christianity is not the name of a religion recognised by Jesus. Could you show the religion named Christianity in the Bible?

Let's address #2 first.  Actually the term *Christian* is used 3 times in the New Testament: [Acts 11:26, Acts 26:28, 1 Peter 4:16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts+11%3A26%2C+Acts+26%3A28%2C+1+Peter+4%3A16&version=CSB).  Etymologically, Christian means "follower of Christ", who calls Jesus as "Christ", which in turn means seeing [Jesus as the "Messiah"](https://www.gotquestions.org/is-Jesus-the-Messiah.html) based on certain interpretation of the Old Testament.  **It is a term for *self-identification* based on our beliefs of who Jesus is**.  Similarly, there are other terms that Christians used as self-identification to highlight other aspects of what following Christ means: Disciple (of Jesus), Brother (of Jesus), Saint, Believer (in Jesus), Follower of the Way, Friend (of Jesus), etc. (see [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Christian_synonyms)).

It is true that God never commanded us to call ourselves "Christian".  What's more important "in the sight of God" is that we **follow Jesus faithfully** according to the teachings of Jesus and his apostles as recorded in the New Testament.  Christians can agree with Muslims that God is All-Hearing, All-Seeing ([Qur'an 42:11](https://quran.com/42?startingVerse=11), [Psalm 139](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Psalm%20139&version=CSB)), and that God looks at the heart, **NOT** what we call ourselves.  According to the New Testament, Jesus himself said that true followers are identified by their obedience ("does the will of [God]", [Matt 7:21-23, Luke 6:46, Luke 13:25-27](https://www.esv.org/Matthew+7:21%E2%80%9323;Luke+6:46;Luke+13:25%E2%80%9327/)).

**But *HOW* do we follow Jesus rightly, truthfully, and faithfully?**  What does ***GOD*** Himself teach us about Jesus?  What is God's ***TRUE WILL*** to which we need to submit?

Muslims and Christians agree that revelation is needed to discover the answers since we cannot just look at our own hearts to know the answers like Buddhism.  That's why Muslims and Christians:

- have **sacred texts** (Qur'an and Bible),
- look up to certain human teachers to **interpret** them ([Tafsir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tafsir) and [Biblical studies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_studies))
- consult **additional writings** that came down to us through the ages ([Hadith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadith) and [Patristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patristics))
- value human contribution to systematize those 2 sources into various [Schools of Islamic Theology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schools_of_Islamic_theology) and various [Christian theologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Christian_theology) (**theory**)
- create systems of ethics and jurisprudence (**morality**): [Halakha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halakha) for Judaism, [Sharia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharia) for Islam, [Canon law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_law) for Catholics, etc.
- develop **religious practice** over time, inculcate and do it in respective communities: [Five Pillars of Islam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Pillars_of_Islam) and [Christian spirituality](https://www.gotquestions.org/spirituality-Christian.html) (prayers, going to church, service, meditation, etc.)

As you can see above, both Muslims and Christians have developed **different practices** based on **different theories** to direct individual Muslims and Christians to follow Jesus faithfully.  **The whole complex of theory + morality + practice is properly called a "religion"**, and the term "Christianity" is simply a **name for that practice**, the same way the term "Islam" is simply a religion's name as well.

But notice that you said Muslims believe **Jesus is a Muslim**, which I take to mean that if Jesus were to live longer and had the benefit of reading the Qur'an, he would have testified that Islam ***IS*** the true practice ("in the sight of God") for submitting to God and that Christianity is an imperfect religion in need of purification from corruption.

Similarly, Christians believe **Jesus is a Christian**, meaning that Jesus showed us how to submit to God properly through a life of prayer (Jesus taught [the Lord's prayer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord%27s_Prayer)), conducting life following the teachings in the [Sermon on the Mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sermon_on_the_Mount), loving others like the [Good Samaritan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parable_of_the_Good_Samaritan), following the teachings that his apostles have taught as recorded in the [New Testament](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Testament), ready to sacrifice / suffer for God like he did, etc.  Our Jesus would have said that **written revelation has ended with the New Testament and subsequent sacred texts (like the Qur'an) are not binding** and need to be subject to the New Testament for proper evaluation.

**CONCLUSION**: At the end of the day, labels don't matter, but distinct labels (like "Christian" and "Muslim") **are STILL needed to truly distinguish spiritual practices** (compare and contrast) so that followers of Jesus and worshipers of God are not confused and can choose WHICH spiritual practice is trustworthy (using our reason) so we all (Muslims and Christians) can be approved in the sight of God based **NOT** on self-identification but on how wholeheartedly we **DO** the religion we individually have chosen.

Similarly for various Christian groups (both Trinitarian and non-Trinitarian), at Judgment Day labels don't matter in the sight of God.  It's more important that a Christian follows Jesus wholeheartedly according to the Christian theology they trust best (whether it is Catholic, Orthodox, Anglican, Lutheran, Reformed, Methodist, Pentecostal, LDS, JW, BU, etc.), although as a Trinitarian I think Trinitarian theology (when understood properly, especially by Catholic Thomism) is a more genuine understanding of the relationship between God and Jesus as portrayed in the Bible, more helpful to appreciate what Jesus did on the cross, and more conducive to a Christian's spiritual growth.

Comment: "Most religions agree with Jesus's teachings" that's true. But No religion without Islam believes in Jesus. Also Islam has the most similar teachings with christianity. But I'm not talking about muslims to be considered christians in the sight of an ideology called christianity. I'm talking about in the sight of God. In God's sight, won't muslims be considered believers and followers of Jesus in the hereafter? And christianity is not the name of a religion recognised by Jesus. Could you show the religion named christianity in the bible?

Comment: @MahmudulHasanJabir I understand your points.  Rather busy today, will try to respond tomorrow morning.  Short response: 1) Yes, Islam is the the closest to Christianity about Jesus; 2) Etymologically, Christian means "follower of Christ" who calls Jesus as "Christ", which in turn means seeing Jesus as the "Messiah", based on certain interpretation of the Old Testament (see explanation [here](https://www.gotquestions.org/is-Jesus-the-Messiah.html)); 3) **"Who is Jesus?"** is indeed the issue; Muslims and Christians **both** claim to have the right answer "in the sight of God".  Who's right?

Comment: I'll point out that certain strands of Christian Quakers don't practice baptism and the Lord's Supper and put forth certain theological arguments denying their necessity. Nonetheless, they're distinct from fully a-Christian Quakers.

Comment: @MahmudulHasanJabir Islam is an Abrahamic religion, because it recognizes the one true God of Abraham (Ibrahim) but it is not possible to harmonize Islamic practice with Christianity because Islamic practice denies grace, because it denies a grace giver.

Comment: @MahmudulHasanJabir I have edited my answer to respond to your comments.  I hope the edit addressed everything.  If not, please comment further.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple I didn’t understand a point. Did Jesus say that new testament is the final and last revelation?

Comment: @MahmudulHasanJabir I added a new section in the answer to address your question.

Comment: @GratefulDisciple Islam didn't came because of bible being corrupted. Rather, Islam says all the prophets came before Muhammad were sent to a specific nation/tribe. But Prophet Muhammad was sent to the whole world as the final prophet, not for any specific tribe. You can see in Quran God always talked about all humankind, not arabs. But You'll see that bible only talks about israeli tribe. And others like African, indian, chinese and all religions talk about their own tribe.

Comment: @MahmudulHasanJabir I hope I successfully showed in [my answer to your other question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/95387/10672) that Jesus too, was sent for the whole world, which is very clear in the NT (there are a lot more indications beyond what I cited in the answer).  You're right that OT's main theme was Israel, but even so, among Israelites they have always understood themselves (especially since the exile) to be light to the nations (i.e. the whole world).  The Bible as a whole (NT included) is clearly written for the whole world.  Great Apostasy is about wrong teachings.

Answer (score 5):

Historically, this was more or less the case.  For a long time, Islam was treated by Christians as a heretical splinter sect of Christianity.  (This view can be found in Dante's *Inferno*, for example.)

That understanding has changed over time, largely due to the way
Islam goes further than even non-Trinitarian Christianity, rejecting the fundamental premise of the New Testament that Jesus is the Son of God.  The Quran says in multiple places that Allah has no son, in contexts making it clear that it is specifically answering and rejecting Christian doctrine.

This, more than anything, is responsible for the view that Muslims are not understood to be Christians.  While there are some churches that consider themselves Christian despite doctrinal differences with mainstream Christianity that leads other religions to dispute that claim — my own church among them — Islam does not consider *itself* Christian to begin with, and actively rejects the doctrine that Jesus is the Son of God.  (By contrast, the Jehovah's Witnesses, who also reject the notion that Jesus is God and believe he was simply a great prophet sent by God as the Messiah and exemplar, still claim that [he is God's "only-begotten Son", and that his life began in heaven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jehovah%27s_Witnesses_beliefs#Jesus_Christ) before his mortal ministry.)

As a matter of policy for Christianity.StackExchange specifically, we consider any religion to be Christian that makes that claim about itself.  But as Islam actively rejects it and does not claim to be a sect of Christianity, but rather a separate branch of the Abrahamic tradition, we accept that self-identification.

Comment: Another person edited my question and changed the point. I don’t agree with that. So this not the answer of my question.

Comment: @MahmudulHasanJabir, "and also Muslim" is a red herring. The Question, in its most recent edit *by you* and in the form the community deemed it acceptable for the site, asks whether Muslims are "Christian". Not calling *themselves* Christian is a perfectly valid and pertinent answer.

Comment: In such literature they are often called Mohammadeans. I'd say it's debatable that it was classified a heresy, depending on the literature. A semantic debate, but still legitimately held. The Catholic church roundly rejected it all the same at the time.

Answer (score 5):

Key to your edited question is your statement that “Muslims are non-Trinitarians, but they believe in Jesus and claim that they follow his teachings”.  In your main question you ask “Can Muslims be considered Muslims and Christians at the same time in the sight of God?”  The main question will be answered after considering the following points.

The first point that must be addressed is whether the Muslim view of Jesus tallies with the Christian view of Jesus.  Here are some fundamental questions that must be answered:

***[1] Do Muslims agree with what Jesus said about his pre-mortal existence in heaven?***

> Through him [the Logos or Word of God] all things were made; without him nothing was made that has been made....  The Word became flesh and made his dwelling among us [Jesus].  We have seen his glory, the glory of the One and Only, who came from the Father, full of grace and truth.” (John 1:3, and verse 14)

> For you granted him [your Son] authority over all people that he might give eternal life to all those you have given him.  Now this is eternal life: that they may know you, the only true God, and Jesus Christ, whom you have sent.  I have brought you glory on earth by completing the work you gave me to do.  And now Father, glorify me in your presence with the glory I had with you before the world began. (John 17:2-5)

***[2] Do Muslims agree with what the Bible says about the resurrection of Jesus?***

> Jesus said to her, “I am the resurrection and the life. Whoever believes in me, though he die, yet shall he live, and everyone who lives and believes in me shall never die. Do you believe this?” (John 11:25-26)

> And you killed the Author of life, whom God raised from the dead. To this we are witnesses. (Acts 3:15)

> Because, if you confess with your mouth that Jesus is Lord and believe in your heart that God raised him from the dead, you will be saved. (Romans 10:9)

***[3] Do Muslims submit to the risen, resurrected and glorified Jesus Christ?***

> All authority in heaven and on earth has been given to me. (Matthew28:18)

> That at the name of Jesus every knee should bow, in heaven and on earth and under the earth, and every tongue confess that Jesus Christ is Lord, to the glory of God the Father. (Philippians 2:10-11)

Those words are quoted from the Old Testament book of Isaiah (chapter 45, verse 43) and were originally applied to Yahweh, the God of Abraham, Isaac, Jacob and Moses.  Will any Muslim worship the risen, resurrected Jesus as the Son of God?  Or do Muslims deny his deity, and continue to claim he did not die and that he is a follower of Muhammad?

***Conclusion:*** You say Muslims believe in Jesus, follow his teachings but do not believe in the Trinity.  A better question would be do Muslims acknowledge his divinity, his pre-existence and his resurrection?  The problem is that Islam does not accept who Jesus REALLY is.  The Jesus of the Bible is not the same as the Isa of the Qu’ran.  The Jesus of the Bible stands out over and above every other qu’arnic prophet, including Muhammad.

***It is for the aforementioned reasons that no Muslim can be accepted by God as a Christian.***  You are either one, or you are the other.  Attempts to merge Christianity with Islam are actually an attempt to water down Christianity and compromise Christian beliefs.  Such an attempt already exists.  https://www.gotquestions.org/Chrislam.html

Answer (score 2):

> Can Muslims be considered Muslims and Christians at the same time?

That depends on what definition of "Christian" is being used.

1. If the definition of "Christian" is "someone who believes that Jesus was a prophet", then it's reasonable to consider trinitarians, non-trinitarians and Muslims to all be Christians
2. If the definition is "someone who believes that Jesus is the Son of God and the Savior of the world", then (as other answers have explained), trinitarians and non-trinitarians are Christians, but Muslims are not Christians
3. If the definition is "someone who receives salvation through Jesus Christ", then who is or isn't considered Christian will vary by sect, but Christians generally don't include Muslims in this category, since most Christians believe that salvation requires faith in Jesus as the Savior of the world, not just as a prophet

Christians usually use something along the lines of definitions 2 or 3; we usually don't use definition 1. So most Christians do not consider Muslims to be Christians (and thus most Christians believe that Muslims are not Christian in God's eyes)

Answer (score 1):

The Catholic Church would not call a Muslim a Christian, for the reasons given in other answers already. But it may be interesting to know that there is a nuance here.

The question was …*in the sight of God*.

The name “Christian” is a very human thing. We like to give names to everything, just like God asked Adam to do. So we divide groups into smaller groups and use words to identify those groups. So we would not call in Muslim a Christian *in the sight of humans*.

But what would God see?

The catholic church teaches, as stated in Lumen Gentium, paragraph 16, of the Second Vatican Council, that salvation is very much possible and in accordance with the will of God who wants everybody saved, for anyone who, to say it in short, is not a Christian but by no fault of their own.

So it might be very possible that *in the sight of God*, the question about being a Christian isn’t as relevant as we make it to be in our world.